# Excel 2016 crash on API timer initiated Workbook.close

Tags: vba, excel, timer

I have a workbook that crashes Excel on close when the close is triggered by an API timer.

Edit: The workbook in link below has nothing but the timer and exit modules and it has the same behavior so it's not an issue with the content.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/x0xdwgj5h34ctdk/Book1.xlsm?dl=0

A few seconds after the workbook closes Excel crashes. I have tried turning the timer off, unhiding all sheets, unloading forms...all the objects are set to `Nothing`.

All I am doing is `Workbooks(ThisWorkbook.Name).Close SaveChanges:=True`??!!

The same sub is called from a UserForm with no problem. The workbook closes without Excel crashing.

How to fix this?

```
Sub ApplicationExit()
'    Call UnloadAllForms
'    DoEvents
'    Sleep 1000
'    Call StopCloseTimer
'DoEvents
'If Application.Workbooks.Count = 1 Then
'    Workbooks(ThisWorkbook.Name).Save
'    Application.Quit
'Else
    DoEvents
    Workbooks(ThisWorkbook.Name).Close SaveChanges:=True
'End If
End Sub
```

The code triggered by the timer is;

```
Sub TimerCalled()

If CloseTimerValue = "" Then Call Reset_CloseTimerValue
DoEvents
If basTimers.CloseTimerValue <= Now() And Not Unlocked Then Call ApplicationExit

On Error Resume Next 'In case sheet is protected
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("JobIndex").Range("CloseCount").Value = Format(Now() - CloseTimerValue, "hh:m:s")


End Sub
```

The userform says;

```
CloseUp:
i = MsgBox("Close Project Register?", vbYesNo, MsgBoxTitle)
Select Case i
    Case vbYes
        Call ApplicationExit
    Case vbNo
        Workbooks(ThisWorkbook.Name).Save
End Select
```

Answer (score 0):

Timer in excel vba is done by using the Application.OnTime command or windows timer, as you are using.

Notice that, to schedule the call for a function (using the upper-mentioned command), it's used APPLICATION, which means it tells EXCEL to execute the call, not your workbook. So, in your case, the workbook is closed, BUT the to-be-called procedure is still scheduled to go off at some time in the future. The error that you get is that the excel doesn't find the procedure and then throws an error.

The reason it crashes in your case is that you are using windows timer to do it. When you close your workbook, your instance of the lib32 is lost and when time comes, Windows can't reach in the memory and then crashes the whole application.

In both cases, it seems that your scheduled procedure is still running.

I suggest that you look into that and consider using application.ontime.

Comment: Closing the Excel instance from application.ontime is worse.

Instead of crashing Excel will shut down/restart several/many times and may require kill via task manager to stop it.